# Scaling amplitudes by two for the FFT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I just read the example of Mablab tutorial, trying to studying the FFT function.
Can anyone tell me that for the final step, why `P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1)`. In my opinion, it is not necessary to multiply by 2.

```
Fs = 1000;            % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period
L = 1000;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector

%--------
S = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
%---------
X = S + 2*randn(size(t));
%---------
plot(1000*t(1:50),X(1:50))
title('Signal Corrupted with Zero-Mean Random Noise')
xlabel('t (milliseconds)')
ylabel('X(t)')

Y = fft(X);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
plot(f,P1)
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of X(t)')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')

Y = fft(S);
P2 = abs(Y/L);
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);

plot(f,P1)
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of S(t)')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')
```

[Matlab sample](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for the multiplication by 2 is that the spectrum returned by `fft` is symmetric about the DC component. Since they are showing the single-sided amplitude spectrum, the amplitude of each point is going to be doubled to account for the contributions of data on the *other side* of the spectrum. For example, the single-sided amplitude of `pi/4` is the amplitude at `pi/4` *plus* the amplitude at `-pi/4`.

The first sample is skipped since it is the DC point and therefore shared between the two sides of the spectrum.

So for example, if we look at the `fft` of their example signal with a 50Hz sinusoid of amplitude 0.7 and a 120Hz sinusoid of amplitude 1.

```
Fs = 1000;            % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period
L = 1000;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector

S = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);

% Compute the FFT
Y = fft(S);

% Compute the amplitudes
amplitude = abs(Y / L);

% Figure out the corresponding frequencies
f = Fs/L*[0:(L/2-1),-L/2:-1]

% Plot the result
plot(f, amplitude)
```

When we plot this, you'll see that it's symmetric and the original input amplitude is only realized by combining the amplitudes from both sides of the spectrum.

[image]

A slightly more explicit version of what they have done would be to be the following which sums the two halves of the spectrum

```
P1(2:end-1) = P1(2:end-1) + P2((L/2+2):end);
```

But since by definition the spectrum is symmetric, the opt to simply multiply by 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could understand now. @Suever

Comment: @suever, the way in which you defined the frequency vector is wrong. You can see from the plot you uploaded, that the two peaks are located at `400Hz` aprox. This is completely different from the expected `50Hz` and `120Hz`. The frequency vector is defined horribly in matlab as `f = Fs/L*[0:(L/2-1),-L/2:-1]`

Comment: @lucianopaz Thanks for pointing that out! I was so focused on the amplitude that I missed the frequency labels. Updated.